# java-serverside for(;;) loop stops when readline() is null

Tags: java, server-side, bufferedreader

I have a few questions about my **server side code**. Since i don't know how to debug the server side code i am asking it here what could be the reason. At my `for(;;)` loop if the if the msg comes **null** the **for loop breaks** before coming to my `if(msg==null)` statement so i can not broadcast it what might be the problem? Thanks

```
public class ChatServer { 
    String gonderen1;
    String alan1;

    private static final int PORT_NUMBER = 8000;
    Map<String, List<PrintWriter>> clients;
    List<PrintWriter> clientwriter;
    ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Creates a new server. */
    public ChatServer() {
        clients = new HashMap<String, List<PrintWriter>>();
        clientwriter = new LinkedList<PrintWriter>();
    }

    /** Starts the server. */
    public void start() {
        try {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER); 
            for (;;) {
                Socket incoming = s.accept(); 
                new ClientHandler(incoming).start(); 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Adds a new client identified by the given print writer. */
    private void addClient(PrintWriter out,String alan) {
        synchronized(clientwriter) {    
            clientwriter.add(out);
            clients.put(alan, clientwriter);    
        }
    }

    /** Adds the client with given print writer. */
    private void removeClient(PrintWriter out) {
        synchronized(clientwriter) {    
            clientwriter.remove(out);
            clients.remove(alan1);  
        }
    }

    private void broadcast(String msg,String alan) {
        for(PrintWriter out : clients.get(alan)){
            out.println(msg);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        new ChatServer().start();
    }

    private class ClientHandler extends Thread {

        private Socket incoming; 

        public ClientHandler(Socket incoming) {
            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        public void run() {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(incoming.getOutputStream()));

                // inform the server of this new client           
                /* ChatServer.this.addClient(out,"mert");
                out.print("Welcome to AndyChat! mert");
                out.println("Enter BYE to exit."); 
                out.flush();*/

                BufferedReader in 
                    = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream())); 
                String msg;
               for(;;)  {
                   msg = in.readLine();
                   if(msg!=null){
                       liste.add(msg);
                       Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<Gonderen>(.*?)</Gonderen>");
                       Matcher mat = pat.matcher(msg);
                       if (mat.find()) {
                           gonderen1 = mat.group(1).replaceAll("\\s",""); // => "3"
                           System.out.println("Gonderen "+gonderen1);
                       }
                       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Alan>(.*?)</Alan>");
                       Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);

                       if (m.find()) {
                           alan1 = m.group(1).replaceAll("\\s",""); // => "3"           
                           out.print("dsa");
                           System.out.println("Alanin adi "+alan1);
                       }
                       if(alan1!=null){
                           System.out.println(clients.get("mert"));
                           ChatServer.this.addClient(out,alan1);
                       }
                   } else {                         
                       for(int i =0;i<liste.size();i++){
                       ChatServer.this.broadcast(msg,"mert");
                       System.out.println("null gelmedi");}
                       break;
                   }

               }

               incoming.close(); 
               ChatServer.this.removeClient(out);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                if (out != null) {
                    ChatServer.this.removeClient(out);
                }
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably does not break. It never makes to if statement because new line has not been received..

Comment: i see that but what can i do to make it receive? @KorayTugay

Comment: Try the read method instead of readLine. Why dont you know how to debug server?

Comment: well i am running the server from the command prompt and looked up for how to debug but couldn't find anything i haven't wrote server side before so i don't really know how can i do it can you suggest a good method for debugging @KorayTugay

Comment: import to server code to eclipse or netbeans, no other easy way

Comment: in the server code you can also send \n if the msg to be sent itself is null and take action for that in the client.

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher mat = pat.matcher(msg);` probably gives you `NullPointerException` if you pass to it a `null` msg.

You should move your `if(msg==null)` check to be before `Matcher mat = pat.matcher(msg);`.

```
pat.matcher(msg)
  calls new Matcher (pat, msg)
  which assigns this.text = msg (which is null) and then calls reset()
  which calls to = getTextLength()
  which returns text.length() // which is where the NullPointerException will be
                              // thrown
```

Comment: get the first part beginning from liste.get(msg) in if(msg!=null)  but didn't work

Comment: @mert What do you mean "didn't work"? What didn't work? Can you edit your question with the updated code?

Comment: i edited now isn't it should work that way if the problem is  Matcher mat = pat.matcher(msg);

Comment: it doesn't throw any exception either it just stops in readline()if it is null